# How to create an executable file for multiple java files and resources?

Tags: java, exe, command-prompt

I am learning about running java programs from the command prompt. I am using this game, the Snake game, as an example. I've created a folder called **Snake** with the 5 files:

- apple.png
- dot.png
- head.png
- Board.java
- Snake.java

Ive adjusted the directories of the images in the Board.java and Snake.java to my current folder, and removed the package since it was no longer needed. In order to run the game, I do the following:

1. Open command prompt
2. Enter "*cd C:\Users\Bipon Roy\Desktop\java\Snake*" **(sets directory of the game folder)**
3. Enter "*javac *.java*" **(compiles all files)**
4. Enter "*java Snake*" **(runs the main class file)**

The game opens after this and is played as usual. **How do I create an executable file that already inputs these command lines for me so I do not have to manually type it out each time?** (Open 1 file which automatically opens the game)

Comment: Start with the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), it explains all things you need, including deployment.

Comment: Any certain videos I should look at first?

Comment: Yes, kitten videos. Then you'll have the strength to **read** the tutorial.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't realize it was a link to a tutorial haha

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Java, so I don't understand why reading a Java tutorial will help. Looks like you are on _Windows_ platform. In order to run several Windows commands without entering each one individually, you use a [batch file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm). Try Googling _windows batch file_.

Comment: @Abra: the correct way to build a simply-executable file for Java programs is to build a JAR file. That is pretty much Java specific.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I see three separate commands that need to be typed. First is to change directory. Second is to compile java code and third is to run compiled java code. How can that be achieved via a JAR file?

Comment: @Abra: you don't build the .jar to run those commands. You build it to avoid having to do it. You compile everything and add the resources and the .class files in to a .jar file so that "run the program" turns into "double-click the jar file".

Comment: [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @JoachimSauer The OP's question is _How do I create an executable file that already inputs these command lines for me so I do not have to manually type it out each time?_ How does building a JAR help the OP not to enter three separate commands? He's obviously developing his game, which means many cycles of modifying code, compiling code and executing code. Again, how can this be achieved via JAR?

Comment: @Abra Because that is what a JAR is... A compiled compressed java program. I think the OP doesn't know this.Can use a program like `maven-shade` plugin to create a `uber` jar then run the jar like `java -jar myjar.jar`

Comment: @Abra Sometimes, like a doctor, you need to read between the lines to figure out what the OP *needs* or intends, not literally what he/she thinks he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, sounds like a JAR file is exactly what I need. A batch file also sounds like a possible solution but I will attempt to create a JAR file since its Java specific (will likely need to create JAR files anyways so why not :) )

Comment: If you are looking for a pure java way to compile, package and run your java code then take a look at the following three tools that each do all those things and choose the one most suitable for you (assuming they are relevant): [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/)